# Making child hierarchyid from parent path using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, hierarchy, hierarchyid

I have an object like below:

```
roleNode = //child hierarchyid,
code = model.code,
name = model.name,
created = now,
createdById = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.FindFirst(CrmClaimTypes.UserId).Value),
updated = now,
updatedById = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.User.FindFirst(CrmClaimTypes.UserId).Value),
IsActive = true
```

My parameters:

```
{
    "parentRoleNode": "1/1/2"
}
```

How can I create a `childNode` from `parentNode` using Entity Framework?

- Note that both "1/1/2" and "1/1/2/1" is available down below at SQL Server Database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check all your nodes until you find the empty node

Create new view model for your entity and change the type object with your model name

```
    public class RoleTreeView
    {
        public object Parent { get; set; }
        public object Child { get; set; }

        public RoleTreeView()
        {
        }

        public RoleTreeView(object parent)
        {
            CreateRoleTreeView(parent);
        }

        public RoleTreeView CreateRoleTreeView(object Parent)
        {
            var model = new RoleTreeView();
            if (Parent.roleNode != null)
            {
                model.Parent = Parent;
                model.Child = //get from db base on id; 
                CreateRoleTreeView(model.Child);
            }
            return model;
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
I just don't know the way to search for all childrenNode of that parentNode.
Ex: 
• Parent: "1/1/2"  
• Current Chidren: "1/1/2/1"  
• Child need to be added: "1/1/2/2"  
• I now think about the way converting to String and then mange by some methods just like parse string..... :(

Comment: @VũThiên each Parents Have only one children?

Comment: @VũThiên You need to create new object var vm = new RoleTreeView(firstParent); The CreateRoleTreeView  function check all models base on if they have any child id

Comment: @VũThiên Your welcome,Just make sure you have correct child hierarchyid